# Изменение класса div по клику на radio кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как убрать черный квадрат по клику на радио кнопку через `display:none`?

Подскажите пожалуйста.

```css
.block {
color: #fff;
background: #000;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input id="myid" class="myclass" type="radio" name="myname"/>
<div class="block">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Или так через jQuery:

```js
$('#myid').on('change', function() { $('.block').hide(); });
```

```css
.block {
color: #fff;
background: #000;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myid" class="myclass" type="radio" name="myname"/>
<div class="block">
</div>
```

Comment: нужно больше жыквери

Answer (score 5):

Можно и на `css` это реализовать, только эти элементы должны иметь одного родителя

```css
.block {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.block {
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: white;
}

#myid:checked~.block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="myid" class="myclass" type="radio" name="myname" />
  <div class="block">
    block-1
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="block">
    block-2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="myid" class="myclass" type="radio" name="myname" 
  onclick="document.querySelector('.block').style.display='none';"/>
```

или

```
.block-hide {
  display:none;
}

<input id="myid" class="myclass" type="radio" name="myname" 
  onclick="document.querySelector('.block').classList.add('block-hide');"/>
```